# How to move a subdirectory in CVS without hacking the repository?

Tags: cvs

I have a CVS repository with multiple directories which contain subdirectories.  I have accidentally added a subdirectory to the wrong top-level directory while doing some work.  In an attempt to clean it up, I went through and did "cvs remove" on the subdirectory and everything below it after making a recursive copy in the correct top-level directory; however, when I go to "cvs add" everything in the right place, CVS is complaining that versions already exist.  Reading a bit of the manual and doing some quick Google searches seem to indicate that fixing this will require hacking the repository (which I don't have access to right now), does anybody know of another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CVS stores a copy of the old folder in the "Attic" in the location you don't want it.  As long as that "Attic" folder is there, CVS has memory of the directory.  Unfortunately, the only want to completely get rid of it, is to "hack" the repository to remove that folder from the "Attic."

The only other thing I can think of is to restore that directory from CVS, just delete the contents (which puts them back in the attic) and commit what you actually want in the folder in the head.